# Space between soft keyboard and edit text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I need to provide some padding between the keyboard and edittext when soft keyboard pops up which generally hides the bottom part of edittext.

When the soft keyboard is opened, i need the full edittext view to be visible.
And more importantly, I can’t go with `android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustResize"`, which doesn’t work good in my use case. I am using "adjustPan".

So how to achieve the same without changing the windowSoftInputMode?

Answer (score 0):

**Create this function for EditText in your class :**

```
private fun View.focusAndShowKeyboard() {

        fun View.showTheKeyboardNow() {
            if (isFocused) {
                post {
                    val imm =
                        context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
                }
            }
        }

        requestFocus()
        if (hasWindowFocus()) {
            showTheKeyboardNow()
        } else {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(
                object : ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener {
                    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
                        if (hasFocus) {
                            this@focusAndShowKeyboard.showTheKeyboardNow()
                            viewTreeObserver.removeOnWindowFocusChangeListener(this)
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }
```

and you can use it like this :

```
txtValue.focusAndShowKeyboard()
```

That's it. Happy coding !!! :~)

Answer (score 0):

`activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)`

Use this in `OnResume` method of your fragment It works for me

Comment: As i already mentioned, I don’t want to use adjustResize which will not be proper for my use case. I don’t want my layout to be pushed up when keyboard is open.